# locate-file function not found in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I want to use the locate-file function in Emacs to find files quickly using file names. This link: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Locating-Files.html says that there is a command function 'locate-file' for this purpose.

But when I try to use this function using: `M-x locate-file` it says `[No match]`. What could be the problem?

Strangely, when the function is present in `describe-function`!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`icicle-locate` or `icicle-locate-file`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#icicle-locate-file), in [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

If you are on GNU/Linux or Unix then use `icicle-locate`, which takes advantage of the OS command `locate`, which uses a periodically updated index created by the OS command `updatedb`.  Because of such indexing, `locate` (and hence `icicle-locate`) is extremely fast. And because this is Icicles you get the same incremental pattern matching you see in Anything (and more).

Comment: Both of them take a lot of time to create the index before suggesting the completion. Is there any way to keep the index generated and ready for use?

Comment: `icicle-locate` should take no time at all -- it uses the external `locate` command.  That external command does create and keep an (external) index.  Or rather, it is the external program `updatedb` that creates or updates the index.  Typically, `updatedb` is run periodically (e.g. daily) via a `cron` job.

Answer (score 1):

`locate-file` is not for interactive use.  There are lots of tools for finding files like `dired-find`.

Comment: `dired-find` does not work the way I want. I just want to type the filename, say "foo.php", and it should search inside a given directory and list all the files like `anything` plugin.

Comment: Well `locate-file` certainly doesn't do that.  If you're happy with anything, then use that.